# Adding time gap and partially concurrent transitions in Sequential Transition JavaFX

Tags: animation, javafx, transition

I would like to repeat the same (similar pattern) JavaFX animation - repeating the pattern of showing a set of buttons, erasing them from the screen after a certain duration, and showing them again after a certain duration. After doing a brief research, I learned about `SequentialTransition` which encapsulates other transition objects and performs them sequentially (as the name suggests) - a good easy example found at https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html. Two things that I need to figure out when using this tool though:

1. I do not want all encapsulated transitions to happen sequentially - I want a few buttons to appear and disappear concurrently and this will be a few `FadeTransition` objects which must not occur concurrently.
2. I want to add time gaps between each transitions (for instance, wait for 5 seconds before the buttons start fading and also wait for 3 seconds before the buttons reappear and etc.). What is a conventional way to add time gaps within `SequentialTransition` (or any transitions in JavaFX for that matter, as Thread.sleep() seems to block the event listener and thus is not suitable)?

Any pointers regarding the two issues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding mixing of transitions you can do parallel transitions right after the sequential transitions finish using an [onFinished event handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setOnFinished%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29). For the time gaps you can use a [PauseTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html).

Comment: Hmm yeah. Didn't think of using the pause transition.